# "Skype" is trying to authenticate user. / Enter PIN to allow this

Tags: macos, skype, pin, macos-bigsur

I'm using `Skype version 8.75.0.140` on `macOS Big Sur 11.6 (20G165)` and this just appeared on my screen...

[image: Skype]

I'm not exactly sure why all of the sudden Skype decided that it needs to authenticate, especially with my PIN?!

Please advise!
Thanks!

---

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: I don't have Skype, but that seems super suspicious.  The English grammar is just a bit off, in 2 places.  You should see what app is "active" (upper left, next to Apple menu), although sometimes these pop-ups doesn't do a full app switch.  Also, try to quit Skype and see if this occurs.  If it does, I'd suspect a virus.

Comment: Skype for Business can have a PIN configured. If this is part of a corporate structure, ask your IT department. I found several pages on setting it up & administering - all for Windows, of course - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/skypeforbusiness/manage/authentication/lock-or-unlock-a-user-pin

Comment: @Tetsujin I used `Skype for Business` a while ago, but I haven't used it in a long time, yet got this prompt few times all of the sudden (even without `Skype for Business` running on my Mac)

Comment: Then I can only guess that either some component of the business version is still installed, or the home version can still read the old settings… so you'll either have to get rid of it or see if you remember the old business PIN [This has nothing to do with your phone PIN or anything similar, it's entirely for Skype to access an account]

Comment: @Tetsujin I took another screenshot and even though I do have `Skype for Business` installed, it's not even running... I used it once to connect to the talk, I didn't setup any PIN. I also checked my `Skype for Business` _IS_ latest version.

Comment: Looks like WebAuthN. However, I’m not familiar with current macOS versions.

Comment: [Here’s some more information](https://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.com/2018/09/smart-card-integration-in-macos-sierra.html), this appears to be a dialog produced by CryptoTokenKit. Remove any smart cards and other tokens and try again.

Comment: @DanielB I think you're right, I also get prompted with Mozilla Firefox now: `Please enter the password for the PKCS#11 token` and I believe that only happens when hardware key is plugged-in.